# probability word questions

Tags: probability

**pita has 12 coins in her bag. There are three £1 coins and nine 50p coins. She takes 3 coins from the bag at random. Work out the probability that she takes exactly £2.50**

I have attempted this question but I got 63/44 and it isn't right and i'm not sure how to do it.

Comment: How did you get $63/44$? Describe that in your question so that we can figure out what you did wrong.

Answer (score 3):

You can solve this in a number of ways.  The arguments used for calculating the probability may either take order into account as being relevant where we take one coin after another in sequence or do it where we take the coins simultaneously.

The easiest and most straightforward method in my opinion is to take it where order is irrelevant and invoking the [hypergeometric distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypergeometric_distribution).  To be fair, when I was a student, I had never actually learned the name of the hypergeometric distribution or known that it was a well understood and common distribution... but had encountered and been using it all the same.  The logic behind how and why it works should hopefully be clear.

Here, we recognize that to have a total of $£2.50$ you must within your three draws have exactly two of the draws be $£1$ coins and the remaining draw be a $50p$ coin.  We temporarily treat each coin as being unique, say for example with a serial number on each.  In doing so, we have made it so that each possible outcome we can describe is equally likely to occur allowing us to find the probability by dividing the total number of "good outcomes" to achieve what we want by the "total number of outcomes."

We construct the denominator of our expression as the total number of ways in which we can select three coins simultaneously.  There are $12$ coins and we are selecting three, so there are $\binom{12}{3}$ possible outcomes, read aloud as "$12$ choose $3$."  This symbol if you have not seen it represents a [binomial coefficient](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_coefficient).  Read more in the link.

The numerator, we pick which two $£1$ coins are used and which one $50p$ coin is used in $\binom{3}{2}\cdot \binom{9}{1}$ number of ways.

Dividing then, we get a final probability of:

$$\frac{\binom{3}{2}\cdot\binom{9}{1}}{\binom{12}{3}}$$

In general, when selecting objects at random without replacement with $N$ objects total, $K$ of which are of one type and the remaining $N-K$ of another type, when selecting $n$ of them the probability that exactly $k$ are of the first type is going to be:

$$\frac{\binom{K}{k}\binom{N-K}{n-k}}{\binom{N}{n}}$$

---

Another option is to treat this as though order matters and approach with arguments based on conditional probability or tree diagrams as was attempted by user @Sanya.  Again, we recognize that exactly one of the three draws will need to be the $50p$ coin and the remaining two will be $£1$ coins.  Here, we will treat the order of coins as they come out as being relevant and will stop after each coin is drawn before continuing to draw the next.

The probability that the first coin is a $£1$ coin is $\frac{3}{12}$.  The Probability that the second coin is also a $£1$ coin *given that the first coin was a £1 coin too* is $\frac{2}{11}$.  The probability that both of these simultaneously happen is then the product of these: $\frac{3}{12}\times\frac{2}{11}$ as per the "multiplication principle of probability" or by the definition of conditional probability.  Continuing, given that the first two coins were both $£1$ coins, the probability that the third coin is a $50p$ coin is $\frac{9}{10}$ and so the probability that you very specifically first draw a $£1$ coin, then draw another $£1$ coin and then draw a $50p$ coin is:

$$\frac{3}{12}\cdot\frac{2}{11}\cdot\frac{9}{10}$$

This however is **not** the probability that you want.  This is only the probability that you drew those coins in that very specific order.  It was also possible that the coins were drawn with the $50p$ coin first followed by two $£1$ coins, or a $£1$ coin in the first and third positions with the $50p$ in the middle.

Calculating each of these individually and adding, we get that the probability of getting one $50p$ and two $£1$ coins in any order is:

$$\frac{3}{12}\cdot\frac{2}{11}\cdot\frac{9}{10}+\frac{3}{12}\cdot\frac{9}{11}\cdot\frac{2}{10}+\frac{9}{12}\cdot\frac{3}{11}\cdot\frac{2}{10}$$

An astute observer would recognize that each of these three individual probabilities are in fact equal and so we could have simply written it as:

$$3\cdot \frac{3}{12}\cdot\frac{2}{11}\cdot\frac{9}{10}$$

Indeed, when generalizing to a much larger problem, you could skip needing to write down each possible valid order and instead use biniomial coefficients to write things out faster.  If you were to simplify the generalized formula you get using binomial coefficients, you would get precisely the general formula I described above when talking about the hypergeometric distribution.

Finally, recognize that the two answers I show here agree and are equal $$3\cdot\frac{3}{12}\cdot\frac{2}{11}\cdot\frac{9}{10}=\frac{\binom{3}{2}\binom{9}{1}}{\binom{12}{3}}$$

Comment: +1 This is a nice answer that moreover is very very educational! Also it makes clear to me that persons exist that have much more patience than me.

Answer (score 1):

Since you have 3 chances. Also, you have to take exactly £2.50. Thus, you have to choose £1 coin - two times and similarly 50p coin - one time. 
We can calculate probability as -

(3/12) * (2/11) * (9/10)

On the first pick, we have chosen the £1 coin and while choosing the second, we are left with only 11 coins now. So that's why 2/11 is the probability for choosing that coin second time.

For the third coin, we are choosing the 50p coin and hence, 9/10. Here, 10 is the number of coins left after two draws.

Similarly, we can choose 50p first, then the other two £1 coins. Or £1 coin, then 50p, then again £1 coin. Thus, we are having 3 cases:

1. £1 £1 50p
2. 50p £1 £1
3. £1 50p £1

Now, the final probability considering all these cases is:

(3/12) * (2/11) * (9/10) *3

Thanks for correcting my mistake here @JMoravitz

Comment: Almost, but you found the probability that the total was 2.50 and the third coin was very specifically the 50p coin.   However, the 50p coin could have occurred first or second as well which throws your answer off by a factor of three.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out this thing. The question was to find the probability. That's why I didn't consider the order. Waiting for the correct answer.

Comment: I don't understand your last comment... do you not agree that taking a 50p coin and then taking two pound coins gets you a total of 2.50?  Your answer can be explained through conditional probability and "tree diagrams" and so you are the one who introduced order when it wasn't strictly necessary and had accidentally ignored all but the one possible valid orders.  If you wanted to avoid order, you could have used a hypergeometric distribution argument instead and used binomial coefficients in calculating your numerator and denominator while ignoring order.

Comment: I'm sorry. I do agree on that.

Comment: I just took an example for solving this question and thought maybe it would be easier from this method.

Comment: I try to allow newer users have the opportunity to answer and correct their mistakes before answering a question like this.  Since you did not correct your mistake even after it was pointed out, please see my answer above for a full explanation.  Again, your answer was nearly correct and was just off by a factor of three, all you needed to do to fix it was say "we recognize that the $50p$ coin could have occurred in one of three positions" and multiplied your result by three to account for the other positions it could have been.

Comment: Now I get it. You have explained everything in the above answer so beautifully. Thanks for correcting. I missed the other two cases.